# Can't import characters due to incorrect code page

Tags: sql-server, ssis, collation, codepages

I have an SSIS job to import data from a flat file into an SQL Server table. I'm having an issue regarding the encoding of the source file and destination table.
The file is an UTF8 encoded CSV file with some standard accented latin characters (ãóé, etc). My destination table is defined as having the Latin1_General_CI_AS Collation, which means I can manually insert the following text with no problem: "JOÃO ANTÓNIO".

When I declare the Flat File source, it automatically determines the file as having the 65001 code page (UTF-8), and infers the **string [DT_STR]** data type for each column. However, the SSIS package automatically assumes the destination table as having the 1252 Code Page, giving me the following error:

```
Validation error. <STEPNAME>: <STEPNAME>: The code page 65002 specified on output column "<MYCOLUMN>" (180) is not valid. Select a different code page for output column "<MYCOLUMN>".
```

I understand why, since the database collation is defined as having that Code Page. However, if I try to set the Flat File datasource as having the Latin1 1252 encoding, the SSIS executes but it imports characters incorrectly:

JOÃO ANTÓNIO (Flat File)-> JOAO ANTÃ“NIO (Database).

I have already tried to configure the flat file source as being unicode compliant, but then when after I configure each column as having a unicode compliant data type, i can't update the destination step since SSIS infers data types directly from the database and doesn't allow me to change them.

Is there a way to keep the flat file source as being CP 1252, but also importing the correct characters? What am I missing here?

Comment: You need to use a Dervived Column Transformation and convert the value from a `DT_STR` using the code page 65002 to a `DT_STR` using the code page 1252. SSIS doesn't allow *any* implicit converting in its nodes, so if you have one (in this case from the code page 65002 to the code page 1252) it generates an error.

Comment: Thanks Larnu, that did the trick. I'm not very experienced with SSIS, so this interface is a bit confusing, i can't really tell what the source data is and what the destination data is. Is there a guide or book you'd recommend on getting up to speed with SSIS?

Comment: Much of what I learned of SSIS I self taught, I'm afraid. Some trial and error. I *did* go to a training course on it way back in 2015, but I don't have any tutorials or books I can recommend (plus such topics are off topic for [so]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Larnu's comment i've been able to get around this problem.

Since SSIS doesn't allow implicit data conversion, I needed to set up a data conversion step first (Derived Column Transformation). Since the source columns were already set up as DTSTR[65002], i had to configure new derived columns form an expression, converting from the source code page into the destination code page, with the following expression:

```
(DT_STR, 50, 1252)<SourceColumn>
```

Where a direct cast to DT_STR is being made, stating the column will have a maximum size of 50 characters and the data will be represented with the 1252 code page.